# Select row by columns value

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm in the situation where I need to select a row in a datatable, which rows are shown in groups of 10, knowing the value of its column.
I already use the following to select the first row in an other occasion.

```
myGroupTable.row(':eq(0)', { page: 'current' }).select();
```

I already tried the following:

```
myGroupTable.row('td:eq(0).contains(' + value + ')').select();
```

with no success...
Any help?

Comment: The first parameter of the `row` method is called `rowSelector` in the documentation for a reason … because it is applied to filter the rows. `:eq(0)` selects the first row … but you are going to have a hard time finding a table _row_ when you use a selector that demands the tag name of that element should be `td` …

Comment: What if I somehow find the index of the row containing the value I have and then select that row with `myGroupTable.row('eq('${index}')').select();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed somewhat with selectors, it should be:

```
myGroupTable.row(`:has(td:eq(0):contains("${value}"))`).select();
```

To refer to the row that **has** in its first column `td:eq(0)` certain value `:contains()`

**UPDATE**

Here's the working demo to get the point:

```js
var srcData = [
  {name: 'Wikipedia', descr: 'Free encyclopedia', url: 'https://wikipedia.com/'},
  {name: 'GitHub', descr: 'Version tracking system', url: 'https://github.com/'},
  {name: 'Stackoverflow', descr: 'Coders community forum', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'}
];

var dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {title: 'Name', data: 'name'},
    {title: 'Description', data: 'descr'}
  ]
});

//That's actually the key part :)
var needle = 'Stackoverflow';
console.log(dataTable.rows(`:has(td:eq(0):contains(${needle}))`).data()[0]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
```

Comment: Using your solution i got this: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: td:eq(0):contains(`

Comment: @Oiproks: I've extended my answer above, so, obviously, that approach is viable